# Jquery UI datepicker - Comparing 3 dates

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to compare 3 dates using jquery ui date picker.

I have the following date fields :

- Date of Enquiry
- Travel from date
- Travel to date

The following rules apply :

- The `Date of Enquiry` must be the most first date
- The `Travel from date` must be after the `Date of Enquiry`
- The `Travel to date` must be after `Travel from date`

I have the following script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#inputField").datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "-1w-4d",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: "-90:+90",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#inputField1").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#inputField1").datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: "-90:+90"

    });

    $("#inputField2").datepicker({
        //defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: "-90:+90",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#inputField1").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay so? What did you try, how do you think it should work? What didn't work? Welcome to SO, but understand that we will/can help if you show us you tried it yourself first. What I see: I downloaded a script, I don't want to spend time, help me. That's not the proper approach :) Show us some work and we can help you! In the end, you have to learn/do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like

```
<label for="enquiry">Enquiry</label>
<input type="text" id="enquiry" name="enquiry"/>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" disabled/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" disabled/>
```

### ​JavaScript Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#enquiry").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+0d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#from").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#to").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+2w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});​
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23t4e/3)**

Answer (score 1):

you could create a custom date comparing function and use in [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event of date picker. This is not the exact answer but a way towards possible solution,

```
....
onSelect: function( selectedDate , inst ) {
   var isValid =  validateTime( selectedDate, inst, this);
   if( isValid ) {
       $( "#inputField1" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
   }
   else {
       //show some appropriate error
   }
}
//where validateTime is custom function returning true or false
```

And custom date comparing function:

```
function validateTime( dateText, pickerInstance, picker) {
   //dateText         - selected date as text
   //pickerInstance   - a reference to the datepicker instance
   //picker           - the datepicker to be validated

   //get the date to check using getDate, like
   var field2DateVal = $("#inputField2").datepicker("getDate");
   //and compare it with other datepicker values
   //return true or false accordingly
}
```

I hope this way works

Answer (score 0):

> - The Date of Enquiry must be the most first date
> - The Travel from date must be after the Date of Enquiry
> - The Travel to date must be after Travel from date

To get you started in the right direction I would start looking at the required business logic and design a solution based on that.

Before setting automatically any other date values from within the `onSelect` of each date picker I would propably separate the validations similar to the below first and go from there :

```
var $enquiryDate = $("#inputField"); // Must be before travel from and before travel to date
var $TravelFromDate = $("#inputField2"); // Must be after enquiry date but before travel to date
var $TravelToDate = $("#inputField2"); // Must be after travel from and after enquiry datedate

function isEnquiryDateValid(dateValue){
     // Must be before travel from and before travel to date

     // Compare date values and return true or false...
}

function isTravelFromDateValid(dateValue){
    // Must be after enquiry date but before travel to date

    // Compare date values and return true or false...
}

function isTravelToDateValid(dateValue){
    // Must be after travel from and after enquiry datedate

    // Compare date values and return true or false...
}
```

You could change this if you want to apply changes based on the values to somethign similar to this:

```
function processSelectedEnquiryDate(dateValue){
     // Must be before travel from and before travel to date

    // Compare dates and set individual dates to specific defaults
    // or
    // show a validation error below the control....
}

function processSelectedTravelFromDate(dateValue){
    // Must be after enquiry date but before travel to date

    // Compare dates and set individual dates to specific defaults
    // or
    // show a validation error below the control....
}

function processSelectedTravelToDate(dateValue){
    // Must be after travel from and after enquiry datedate

    // Compare dates and set individual dates to specific defaults
    // or
    // show a validation error below the control....

    // or simply show a validation error below the control....
}
```

Setting default values on each control based on a selected value is more complex than validating each value selected and displaying a validation error below a control, i.e: `The tavel to date cannot be less than the travel from date`